# Python Javascript framework to use with cherrypy and Mako

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mako

I am just learning python and python web apps so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

I am writing a web app in python with cherrypy + mako (+ html), and now I am diving into the javascript part of it.
Honestly, the rest was already enough to learn...
So I was wondering about using a python framework to sort of abstract the javascript syntax from me.
(I am mostly a c* dev, python is already different enough to keep me busy)

I don't (yet) need any fancy javascript, although I have already started using jquery and jquery-ui, but I don't understand the syntax well enough and it takes me a long time to do anything...
(For example I have not yet found how to get the javascript and mako to interact with each other in a client server way.)

I have learned about pyjamas and other frameworks as such. What would you recommend?

Comment: Coming from C languages, I think you'd have an easier time learning js than with python; just stay away from doing too much functional programming in it (which you can) and pretend it's procedural until you get comfortable. There will be a lot of overhead to using pyjamas that I don't think you'll really need (given js's syntactic similarity to a c* lang)

Comment: Alright, if that is the case I will keep doing things manually then, it does seem a little complex to *have* to do that in 2012, but yet I still code pretty much every thing manually at work for a non-web app so no reason to expect anything different I guess. Thanks!

Comment: If you know java you might want to check out [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/learnmore-sdk) if you really don't want to write js. But with jQuery (or a lighter library like [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/)) you won't have to write much boilerplate

Comment: It was more about learning the syntax than anything else, but I'll take your word on and keep doing it manually if it is a good way. Thanks.

Comment: You were right, once I knew what to look for, it was fairly (still plenty of room to grow for sure, but at least it already works...), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you need the server and client to communicate about.  If you give us a specific problem we can give more specific answers.

Here's a javascript ajax call.  It's straight javascript (no framework) and what you would refer to as "not fancy".

```
function AddToCart_Clicked(SKU, Quantity)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('HeaderShoppingCartlink').innerHTML = 'Shopping Cart (' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')';
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","/ProductNavigation/AddToCartJS?SKU=" + SKU + "&Quantity=" + Quantity, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This function adds an item to a user's shopping cart.  The function sends a GET request to the Cherrypy function AddToCartJS in the class ProductNavigation with the variables SKU and Quantity.  The CherryPy function looks like this.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def AddToCartJS(self, SKU, Quantity):
    CurrentShoppingCart = ShoppingCart()
    CartID = CurrentShoppingCart.AddToCart(SKU, Quantity)
    return CurrentShoppingCart.GetCartCount()
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: For now I am trying to get something super simple: the user would type the beginning of some path in a jquery-ui autocomplete text box and then I want the python to give the possible local paths that would match it. ie if user types "/ho" I want to send back "/home" as a suggestion. I already have the js autocompletion form, and writing the python function, I am just missing the glue in between. Thanks!

Comment: You got it.  Let me know if you need any more help.  Please accept my answer if it correctly answers your question.

Comment: Looking a bit more at your code (I'll actually try it once home...) I am not sure how you use the value from AddToCartJS. I see how the JS calls it but not how to receive the returned value. Would it just be "var return = xmlhttp.send();" ? edit: oh I think I got it: ".responseText" I guess the send() is blocking then.

Comment: I got it all working, thank you so much!